# Jet/ACE SQL, iif statement, 2 false values same column

Tags: sql, jet, iif

I have the following `iif` statement in my sql query within excel.

```
iif(master.[Canada] = '0' or master.[Canada] = ' ' or master.[Canada] IS NULL,master.[USA], master.[Canada]) as Stackoverflow
```

but I want to add something like `iff([Stackoverflow] is not null, [Stackoverflow], "n/a") as Stackoverflow` but cannot have duplicate alias'.

Does anyone know how to do two false conditions? I need to have my blanks in Stackoverflow column show as N/a.

the logic is like this,

```
+--------+--------+---------------+
| Canada |  USA   | Stackoverflow |
+--------+--------+---------------+
|  12345 |  35262 |         12345 |
|  15678 |  52367 |         15678 |
|        |  97536 |         97536 |
|  17893 |  35252 |         17893 |
|      0 | 120321 |        120321 |
+--------+--------+---------------+
```

But what if stackoverflow is null, I want to put n/a's there

Trying something like:

`iff(master.[Canada] <> ' ', iif(master.[Canada] = '0' or master.[Canada] = ' ' or master.[Canada] IS NULL,master.[USA], master.[Canada]), "n/a") as best_id`

But cannot get it to work. `undefined funcation iif`

Comment: Two false conditions? Can you explain all of the conditions and your desired results? You can nest `iif()` statements, but if we nest your new `iif()` then there is no change for `master.[ISIN]` to come through (or it's not clear what you are wanting). Perhaps share some sample data and your desired results so we can help write this up.

Comment: Use `iif([Stackoverflow] is not null, [Stackoverflow], "n/a") as Stackoverflow1`

Comment: I want it in the same column lol, not a new one.  I added some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using nested `IIF()`, you must equate the number of closing parenetheses with open parenetheses. Below indents the *expression*, *truth part*, *false part* of each `IIF()` for emphasis:

```sql
IIF(master.[Canada] <> '0' AND TRIM(master.[Canada]) <> '' AND master.[Canada] IS NOT NULL, 
    master.[Canada], 
    IIF(master.[USA] <> '0' AND TRIM(master.[USA]) <> '' AND master.[USA] IS NOT NULL, 
        master.[USA], 
        'n/a'
       )
   ) as Stackoverflow
```

Comment: thanks for this, query executes fine, however I am still getting blank cells as a result. Perhaps instead of the 2nd iif, can we just do a blank cell = n/a type of query?

Comment: See update logic. It is because of `USA` being empty/null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
iif([Stackoverflow] is not null, iif(Nz(master.[Canada],'0') = '0' or master.[Canada] = ' ',master.[USA], master.[Canada]) , "n/a") as Stackoverflow1
```

Comment: circular reference error. I think it is because stackoverflow is being used in the beggining when it is not yet formed.

Comment: @excelguy Yes, just change column name as Stackoverflow1

Comment: But i want it to be stackoverflow, in that same column, not a newly created column

Comment: @excelguy The above expression has both the conditions you were looking for and you will have 1 column as output i.e. StackOverflow1

Comment: Can we name the output Stackoverflow somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, as it will refer to existing field.